# How can I stop receiving Firebase database security alerts?

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm new to React Native. I made an application with words in two languages. All of the words are in the firebase realtime database. Everyday the security warning coming from Firebase. There is no login with a user name and password in the application and I do not want to log in to the application this way. I added anonymous authentication to the app to fix the security issue. I edited the Firebase security rules as follows. But still the same security message comes up. How can I solve this problem?

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Comment: You've tagged your question with `google-cloud-firestore`, yet the security rules in your question are for the Realtime Database. Both databases are part of Firebase, but they are completely separate and have their own access rules that don't affect each other. If the emails are for Firestore, please show the rules you have there. If the emails are for Realtime Database, please edit to fix your tagging.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I fixed. Do you have any answer for my question?

Comment: Why have you added anonymous authentication? Is your concern only with the security warning you are receiving?

Comment: I added anonymous authentication to be able to define security rule

Comment: Again the above question, Is your concern only with the security warning you are receiving? Do you want to stop getting such security warnings?

Comment: Yes, my concern only with the security warning I am receiving and I want to stop getting this security warnings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules you have allow anyone who is signed in to your back-end full read access to the entire database. This is only a very basic layer of security.
It is also true that this is more secure than just granting everyone access to your database, at least they have to be signed in.

If you enable any auth provider in Firebase Authentication, anyone can sign in to your back-end, even without using your app. And once they are signed in, they can read anything in your database. I would suggest structuring your security rules in a more secure way. You can have a look at the documentation on [avoiding insecure rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/insecure-rules).

If your rules intentionally allow public reading of all data, you don't store any user data, and you are willing to pay the charges for everyone reading all data, then your rules fit your intended usage. In that case the email and alerts  are indeed very noisy. Luckily Firebase provides a way to stop these alerts. To stop the alerts you have to follow the following steps -

- Visit
  https://console.firebase.google.com/subscriptions/project/your-project-id
- Then you will get the following page -
  [image]
- Here under the **Realtime Database** section you have to just untick
  the two boxes which are right to **Your Realtime Database has
  insecure rules**. The first box which is below **In Firebase** column
  will stop Firebase Console alerts and the second box which is below
  the column **Email** will stop receiving the alerts on email.

You can go through [this document](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7276542?hl=en&ref_topic=6399725) to know about Firebase Alerts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use firebase authentication.Then below code will work for you.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid != null",
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

Otherwise you can use https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config

Comment: As I said, I used firebase anonymous authentication and edited the way I wrote the rules. But the warning still comes. I want to solve this problem by using database instead of using remote config.

Comment: firebase anonymous authentication will work or not, i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the double quotes i think

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": auth.uid != null,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```